# Is there a difference in taste between female and male beef?

Tags: beef

A friend said that male beef is more expensive.  I'm thinking she really means the difference in taste of different breeds or some other criteria that makes some beef more expensive. Is there a difference?

Comment: I thought most males were culled for veal or 'baby beef', so they didn't have to deal w/ mature bulls roaming around.

Answer (score 3):

Per this [link from MSU](http://msue.anr.msu.edu/news/do_steers_or_heifers_produce_better_beef);

> heifer carcasses had slightly more marbling than steer carcasses, but
>   USDA quality grade was not significantly different.

So not enough of a quality / taste difference to bother with...

> live heifers averaged $149.80 and steers averaged $149.70 per
>   hundredweight

Apparently, heifers (female) are more expensive than steers (castrated male)... by 10 cents per hundred weight.